# Paste hindi text from pdf to HTML/XML

Tags: html, pdf, hindi

I've a text as `Bharat` written in hindi in PDF.

I am creating a web page where in i need to display this as it is in my webpage. when trying to copy the content and paste it is getting rendered as some garbled text. I've installed the corresponding font and when seen in ms-word it is showing correct, can you please let me know how can i show/display it as it is.

I get the below when i paste it directly.

```
fpfdRlh;
```

Thanks

Comment: Would be nice to see what you have tried with so far.

Comment: Hi @Gustaf, nothing was done, i just directly copy pasted the data. and this was issue

Comment: The problem lies in your PDF [\*]. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637633/parsing-pdf-files/6657121, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107759/strange-behaviour-of-a-pdf-to-text-conversion, and many, many more. [\*] Or with your expectations. The PDF format does not guarantee "exact copying of text is always possible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you save the files as using UTF-8 encoding. Also use UTF-8 as the webpage's charset in the head.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

EDIT: I just tried this and it works great for me. Could it be a browser issue?

Code I tried for reference:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>देवना</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And a JsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/zuymyz00/

Comment: Updated my answer to include some more information.

Comment: I can see this, but the issue comes when copying text from PDF and pasting it into text editor

Comment: Make sure your text editor actually supports UTF-8. I would recommend Sublime Text.

Comment: i'm diretly pasting it into visual studio and altova XML spy, when pasted the content is grabled

Comment: Please try using another text editor and see if it solves the problem. Pasting hindi into Sublime Text worked fine for me.